# After Pose Estimation 3D Coordinate Axes Misplaced

Tags: opencv, image-processing, c++14, image-recognition, opencv-solvepnp

As a newbie I'm trying calculate pose of an planar object using OpenCV's solvePnP. Howeve, I see a weird output. The axes I draw always draws axes on the corner of my frame. To draw my axis I use:

drawFrameAxes(frame_copy, cameraMatrix, distanceCoeffisions, rvec, tvec, length);
The output I get is as follows:

P.s. (X:red, Y: green, Z: blue)

[output of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaRVa.png)
[output of my code_highlight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EnTJ.png)

I don't have any depth information
I am not sure if this is true but to obtain 3D points I use inliers and define the z coordinate as 0.

```
Points.push_back(Point3f(inliers[i].pt.x, inliers[i].pt.y, 0));
```

So what could be the problem, any resource pointers or suggestions is my guest.

**Solved the problem**

Solution :
Fixed camera calibration and problem solved.

Thanks!

Comment: Where are the axis supposed to be drawn? Why is it a problem that they are located where they are?

Comment: It supposed to be on top of the hand-drawn chessboard. Yet I solved the problem, my camera calibration was faulty therefore axes drawn on to wrong place. After using correct calibration parameters it drawn on to correct place.